# Getting a time difference between a certain time range condition using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to find the difference between a start time and an end time within a certain time range.

In my spreadsheet my goal is to charge different Off and On Peak Time  Electricity Rates.

I have attached an Off and On Peak Time Table below.

There are rates during the Winter and Summer Season

**Off and On Peak Time Charges**

[image: Peak Time Charges]

I have attached below my spreadsheet of what I am trying to solve.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egsFi.png)

In my formula I am trying to say if it is Winter time and it is On-Peak Time use this formula in Column I.

My formula in Column I is

```
=IF(AND(G2="Winter"),IF(C2>D2,MAX(0,MIN(D2,WinterOnPeakUpper1)-MAX(C2,WinterOnPeakLower1)),MAX(0,WinterOnPeakUpper1-C2)+MAX(0,D2-WinterOnPeakLower1)))
```

> C2 = Start Time
> D2 = End Time
>
> WinterONPeakLower1 = 6:00am
> WinterONPeakUpper1 = 6:00pm

I keep getting a result of 00:00 instead of a value.

Should I be using DateTime instead Time to get my desired result?

Thank you,

Bob

Comment: Hi @Bob ,, your screen shot & attached sample data are two different info,, I'm little confused that C2 & D2 are only TIME or Date Time Stamp cells ,, since your data has Date & Time both then elapsed time must consider the DAY also (24 Hrs).

Comment: Hi @Bob ,, [Edit] your post & be specific that what you are testing with formula the DATE TIME stamp cells or only cells has TIME,,,!

Comment: Hi @RajeshS I have edited my post. Thank you for the feedback. You are right, using DateTime would be more effective and efficient. How would I implement using Max and Min using DateTime instead of Time only?

Comment: Hey @Bob,, in your formula the False part returns `ZERO` since the cell format is either `GENERAL` or `NUMBER`,, if you apply `HH:MM` then you get `06:50`,, even`[H]:mm` doesn't works. **Actually result should `16:26`,, therefore my suggestion is simply use `=D2-C2`,, and apply `[H]:mm` cell format you get the correct result (no need to use MAX)**.

Comment: @RajeshS what if I want to use DateTIME  instead of just Time only?

Comment: Hey @Bob ,, that's what I'm trying to say that instead of TIME only U must use DATE & TIME Stamp like,,`01/17/2020  8:24:29 PM`. BUT don't use your formula with `MAX`, since it gives wrong result.

Comment: Hey @RajeshS, yes I understand but how can I use DATE & TIME Stamp within a certain time range, if I do not use MAX or MIN?

Comment: you are already using check the screen shot after Season U have Time column that has DATE TIME stamp and in attached screen shot Col A & B are DATE TIME stamp,, simply use `B2-A2` & apply `[H]:mm` (24 Hrs Time format, you get correct answer!!

Comment: Hi @RajeshS. Yes I understand using B2-A2 as getting the difference, but how do you get the time difference for a certain time range condition from 19:00- 07:00?